# Google map is not loading If I call that page using AJAX

Tags: jquery

I am loading pages using AJAX. For that I have a "Home" link (when I open the portal that page will be opened) and another link, by clicking that link that page will open again. But during second call the Google map is not loading.

```
var gMapsLoaded = false;
var geocoder;
window.gMapsCallback = function(){
    gMapsLoaded = true;
    $(window).trigger('gMapsLoaded');
}
window.loadGoogleMaps = function(){
    if(gMapsLoaded) return window.gMapsCallback();
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src","https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&callback=gMapsCallback");
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    function initialize(){
    var sourceLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.878492, -87.627243);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: sourceLatlng

        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap1'),mapOptions);
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: sourceLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Chicago'
                });
        marker1.setIcon('./img/red.png');
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
        $('#safety_score').hide();
        $('#landing').show();
        });
    }
    $(window).bind('gMapsLoaded', initialize);
    window.loadGoogleMaps();
});
function codeAddress() {
      var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
```

The click function is not working and also other functions are not working.

Comment: It would help to see the relevant part of your HTML too, in case there is an error with that.

Comment: One simple trick is to just put a console.log statement at the beginning of each function - then you can see if loadGoogleMaps() is getting called on the reload. If it's not, you can back up and see why. If it is and the map's still not appearing, perhaps the element where it's supposed to appear is no longer there.

Comment: @Matt Thanks its printing 2nd times also but 
its show this error
"You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

but i didn't included the Google Maps API multiple times

Comment: On reload, the first element might still be there; you might try removing the map element if it exists, before creating it again. You might also try taking everything but the map itself out of the ajax-loaded page, so the connection to the API is only loaded on initial page load, but the map is loaded when the ajax returns.

Comment: @Matt Can you suggest me how can I include the Google API only once. I have tried with Flag variable but its not working

Comment: In your loadGoogleMaps function, you're inserting the google maps library in a script tag. If you load that in the <head> section of your page, and then let loadGoogleMaps just load the map itself, that may help.